# How to highlight current node in views

Tags: views, 6

I made a panel for showcasing individual nodes. That panel has a left column that contains a view with a list of all nodes (think teasers), and a right column with the node content.

In the view which generates the list of nodes in the left column,
how can I highlight the current node?

Answer (score 1):

If you list complete node teasers, it means, the nodes are rendered by node.tpl.php. So just add a class to the node template in _preprocess_node something like this:

```
$node = $vars['node'];
$menu_object = menu_get_object();

if ($menu_object && $menu_object->nid == $node->nid) {
  $your_custom_class = 'this-is-the-actual-node';
}
```